# Several conditions on the same table

Tags: sql

I've inherited an excel file converted to a database and I try to figure out the people who went to several locations.

```
| Customer    | email          |   ZIP | shop |
| John Smith  | js@mail.com    | 75016 |    1 |
| Mary King   | mary@ymail.com | 97430 |    2 |
| John Smith  | js@mail.com    | 75016 |    3 |
| Ivan Turtle | ivan@mail.com  | 56266 |    5 |
| Mary King   | mary@ymail.com | 97430 |    5 |
| John Smith  | js@mail.com    | 75016 |    5 |
```

Eg : John Smith had been to 1, 3, 5 
      Mary King to 2, 3

I tried to use email as a key but can't figure out how to solve this one

Comment: by several locations I mean in different id in the shop column

Comment: Can there be duplicate rows?

Answer (score 0):

assuming each row specifies a separate location,

```
select customer, count(*)  as countOfLocation
from TABLE
group by customer
having count(*) > 1
order by countOfLocation desc
```

Is the simplest answer

Answer (score 0):

I believe something like this will work for you.

Find all customers who have been to more than one shop, and then join back to get the details of each customer.

This will give back multiple rows per person, one for each shop they have been to. If all you care about is the names of customers, you can simply use the second `SELECT`

If you want one row per customer and a CSV of the shops, you will have to do a bit of joining.

```
SELECT a.*
FROM Customers a
INNER JOIN 

-- Find all customers who have been to more than one shop.
(SELECT email
FROM Customers
GROUP BY email
HAVING COUNT(shop) > 1) b

ON a.email = b.email
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this if is Sql server:

```
select customer, count(distinct(shop))
from table
group by customer, shop
having count(distinct(shop)) > 1
```

or, you only want to know how many places they visited:

```
 select customer, count(distinct(shop))
    from table
    group by customer, shop
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to show the user name and shop seperating by comma in one row use this

```
SELECT  Customer
       ,STUFF((SELECT ', ' + CAST(shop AS VARCHAR(10)) [text()]
         FROM 'ur table'
         WHERE customer = t.customer
         FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
        .value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,2,' ') List_Output
FROM 'ur table' t
GROUP BY customer
```